# How can I reorder a flextable's headers when using tabulator() in R?

Tags: r, flextable

Here is the current flextable:

[image]

Here is the general example data:

[image]

```
library(flextable)

dat <- data.frame(question = c("Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction"),
                 column_one = c("Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"),
                 column_one_order = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 column_two = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "West", "East", "West", "East"),
                 column_two_order = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                 row_name = c("Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food"),
                 row = c("Pizza", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger"),
                 percent = c(0.83679353, 0.341159874, 0.084278807, 0.071733007, 0.363397833, 0.405083242, 0.094760815, 0.762002269, 0.782725923, 0.657853129),
                 standardError = c(0.824884898, 0.69073481, 0.664255159, 0.099570678, 0.735837865, 0.940523571, 0.933454698, 0.669219927, 0.669924278, 0.537262473))

dat

cft <- tabulator(
  x = dat,
  rows = "row",
  columns = c("question", "column_one","column_two"),
  `P` = as_paragraph(percent),
  `SE` = as_paragraph(standardError)
)

ft <- as_flextable(cft)
ft
```

Is there a parameter or a method where I can rearrange the header based on columns: ***[column_one_order]*** and ***[column_two_order]***? So I would want to see **Portion Size** before **Region** (which flextable automatically does) and below that would be **Small**, **Medium**, **Large** and then **West** and **East**.

My understanding is that tabulator() is automatically arranging it alphabetically when I would like to have it in a more specific order.

Comment: Could you please specify which library is `tabulator() ` from and edit your sample so that it becomes valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control orders by using factor instead of characters (as with ggplot2 or table), in that case factor levels are used as order and not alphabetical order:

```
library(flextable)

dat <- data.frame(
  question = c("Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction"),
  column_one = c("Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"),
  column_one_order = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  column_two = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "West", "East", "West", "East"),
  column_two_order = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  row_name = c("Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food"),
  row = c("Pizza", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger"),
  percent = c(0.83679353, 0.341159874, 0.084278807, 0.071733007, 0.363397833, 0.405083242, 0.094760815, 0.762002269, 0.782725923, 0.657853129),
  standardError = c(0.824884898, 0.69073481, 0.664255159, 0.099570678, 0.735837865, 0.940523571, 0.933454698, 0.669219927, 0.669924278, 0.537262473)
)

dat
dat$column_one <- factor(dat$column_one, levels = c("Portion Size", "Region"))
dat$column_two <- factor(dat$column_two, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "West", "East"))
cft <- tabulator(
  x = dat,
  rows = "row",
  columns = c("question", "column_one", "column_two"),
  `P` = as_paragraph(percent),
  `SE` = as_paragraph(standardError)
)

ft <- as_flextable(cft)
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! I did not know about factors able to be sorted whereas characters are stuck alphabetical. I can manipulate the data to achieve what I need based on this concept for the actual dataset. Thanks for another informative answer!